# Git: What formats are supported by @{}?

Tags: git

I am reading [git-book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection). It says, to show which commits your HEAD was pointing 2 months ago, use `git show HEAD@{2.months.ago}`.

Some other useful things you can do with `@{}`

- To see where your branch `my-branch` was pointing yesterday, do `git show my-branch@{yesterday}`
- To see nth prior value of your HEAD of your repository use git show `HEAD@{n}`

From above it seems, there are different formats that are supported by `@{}` which are not limited to the above.

- What formats are supported by `@{}` in `git` ?
- Above example shows for 2 months ago, suppose I want to see for 2 years 4 month 3 day 4 minutes ago or something like that. Is there any format for such thing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What formats are supported by @{} in git ?

It can also be used with

```
# as you figures out git log
git log
git diff 
git stash stash
git reflog
git merge
```

And many more commands which use references to HEAD and or commits.
The concept is to use this shorthand instead of using the SHA-1

For example:

#### Upstream shorthand

> When you have a tracking branch set up, you can reference its upstream branch with the `@{upstream}` or `@{u}` shorthand.
> So if you’re on the master branch and it’s tracking origin/master, you can say something like `git merge @{u}` instead of `git merge origin/master` if you wish.

---

> Above example shows for 2 months ago, suppose I want to see for 2 years 4 month 3 day 4 minutes ago or something like that. Is there any format for such thing ?

There is not such format for such a strict date. you can use weeks, days etc not a complex combination. if you wish to do it you will have to write script for that

git log supports the `--relative-date`

> **`--relative-date`/ `--date=relative`**
> Display the date in a relative format (for example, “2 weeks ago”) instead of using the full date format.

More info:

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#git-log---dateltformatgt

Comment: thanks @CodeWizard, Would you care editing your answer to fit in my second question or point me to a link.

Comment: something like `2.years.4.months.3.days` ?

Comment: You can get the time in milliseconds and write your script to filter the desired date.